# What 10m USB extension cable can I use for a USB display?

Tags: usb, display, cable, displaylink

The [Lenovo LT1421](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/product-and-parts/detail.page?DocID=PD015702) is a 14 inch monitor that can be connected using a USB B mini to USB A cable. It is shipped with a 1.8 meter cable which is too short for my purpose.

USB is limited to 5 meter, but there exist ["active" USB cables](http://www.ebay.com/itm/30FT-10M-USB-2-0-Extension-Repeater-Cable-Signal-Booster-A-Male-to-A-Female-G-/190701085292) that boost the signal. Are such cables sufficient for DisplayLink devices such as this Lenovo monitor or do they only work for things like keyboards? Should I consider other cables or devices instead?

Comment: Interested in finding out if anyone has ever used these.

Comment: The included cable is a USB-y one by the way, for sufficient power I probably need to connect a USB wall charger. I am still interested whether this is really necessary. The main concern is high signal transfer (loss/corruption/latency) though.

Answer (score 0):

Plugable [claims that their 10M USB extension cable](http://plugable.com/products/USB2-10M) works with DisplayLink USB displays (emphasize mine):

> Connect USB printers, scanners, displays, keyboards, etc from across
>   the room with this 10 meter / 32 foot USB 2.0 extension cable. Active
>   repeater (bus powered single port hub) and a premium shielded cable
>   enables this unit to have 2x the length of a standard USB cable. The
>   tradeoff, however, is devices with precise timing requirements (isoch
>   devices, usually USB video cameras) will not work with this cable.
>   Will work with nearly all other devices: devices such as printers,
>   scanners, **DisplayLink USB displays**, keyboards, mice, and most
>   miscellaneous USB devices.

I am unable to verify their claim, nor do I know whether it this cable can be connected with the existing USB-A/USB-B mini connector.